# Angular 7 routing error base-href gets prepended to path

Tags: angular, routes, tabs, ionic4

I'm using the ionic component `ion-tabs` and `ion-tab-button` with `href="/tabs/path*"` to navigate through my app.

Scenario to reproduce:

1. Click first time to `path2` (OK)
2. Click to `path1` (OK)
3. Click to `path2` (NOK) base-href gets prepended like `/fr/tab/path2`

   ```
   <ion-tab tab="path1">
       <ion-router-outlet name="path1"></ion-router-outlet>
   </ion-tab>
   <ion-tab tab="path2">
       <ion-router-outlet name="path2"></ion-router-outlet>
   </ion-tab>

   <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
       <ion-tab-button tab="path1" href="/tabs/(path1:path1)">
           <ion-icon name="list-box"></ion-icon>
           <ion-label i18n>path1</ion-label>
       </ion-tab-button>

       <ion-tab-button tab="path2" href="/tabs/(path2:path2)">
           <ion-icon name="albums"></ion-icon>
           <ion-label i18n>path2</ion-label>
       </ion-tab-button>
   </ion-tab-bar>
   ```

Routing module Tabs:

```
{
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            redirectTo: '/tabs/(path1:path1)',
            pathMatch: 'full'
        },
        {
            path: 'path1',
            outlet: 'path1',
            loadChildren: '../path1/path1.module#pathModule1'
        },
        {
            path: 'path2',
            outlet: 'path2',
            loadChildren: '../path2/path2.module#pathModule2',
        }
    ]
},
{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/tabs/(path1:path1)'
}
```

Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work with routerLink directive

```
<ion-tab-button tab="path1" 
                [routerLink]="['/tabs/', { outlets: { 'path1': ['path1'] } }]"
                routerLinkActive="active"
                [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }"
>
```

[Angular doc [routerLink] directive](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink)

However, the url is really ugly when i navigate throw the app like:

`localhost:4200/fr/path1(path1:path1//path2:path2//path3:path3)`

If you have a cleaner solution don't hesitate ! share it :)

**EDIT**:

It seems to be fixed in ionic **`4.0.0-beta.17`** !